# After initial_split(), how to change target from chr to fct

Tags: r, tidymodels

I want to be able to run the `last_fit()` model, however it seems that I cannot do that when the target is not a factor. I can normally change it when it is in the standard dataframe form - but when its this data type, I am not sure what to do.

Error Message:

```
x train/test split: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/1:
  Error in `check_outcome()`:
  ! For a classification model, the outcome should be a factor.
Warning message:
All models failed. Run `show_notes(.Last.tune.result)` for more information. 

Error in `check_outcome()`:
! For a classification model, the outcome should be a factor.
```

Below is some sample code I made to recreate the problem in an easy dataset-

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

# Modelling Data
###

df <- read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/netj/8836201/raw/6f9306ad21398ea43cba4f7d537619d0e07d5ae3/iris.csv") |> 
  mutate(
    virg = case_when(
      variety == "Virginica" ~ 'yes',
      TRUE ~ 'No',
    )) |> 
  select(-variety)


# split data
df_split <- initial_split(df, prop = .75,
                          strata = virg)

# eg of training data switched to fct
df_training <- df_split %>% 
  training() |> 
  mutate(virg = as.factor(virg))

# eg of testing data switched to fct
df_test <- df_split %>% 
  testing() |> 
  mutate(virg = as.factor(virg))

# rf model
rf_model <- rand_forest() %>% 
  # Set the engine
  set_engine('randomForest') %>% 
  # Set the mode
  set_mode('classification')

# last_fit()
df_last_fit <- rf_model %>% 
  last_fit(virg ~ sepal.length +
             sepal.width +
             petal.length +
             petal.width,
           split = df_split
  )
```

Comment: Just FYI, the `iris` dataset is built-in to R, you don't need to read it in from a gist.

Comment: You do need to get it from somewhere else if you want to use those variable names. Although using the builtin `iris` does get you a "Species" value tha tis a factor.

Comment: If you just add the line `df$virg <- factor(df$virg)` to your code immediately after the code that creates df, the error goes away.

Answer (score 1):

We recommend that you set that up in your data before you use `initial_split()`:

```r
library(tidymodels)

my_split <- 
  readr::read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/netj/8836201/raw/6f9306ad21398ea43cba4f7d537619d0e07d5ae3/iris.csv") |> 
  mutate(
    virg = case_when(
      variety == "Virginica" ~ 'yes',
      TRUE ~ 'No',
    )) |> 
  select(-variety) |>
  mutate(virg = as.factor(virg)) %>%
  initial_split(prop = .75, strata = virg)
#> Rows: 150 Columns: 5
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr (1): variety
#> dbl (4): sepal.length, sepal.width, petal.length, petal.width
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
```

Notice that now you have a factor in your training set (also your testing set):

```r
training(my_split)
#> # A tibble: 112 × 5
#>    sepal.length sepal.width petal.length petal.width virg 
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 No   
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 No   
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 No   
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 No   
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 No   
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 No   
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 No   
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 No   
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 No   
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 No   
#> # … with 102 more rows
#> # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

It is a better idea to set up the data types before you split and not try to mess with the split itself. In tidymodels, any fitting you do for a classification model will require that your outcome is a factor.